# CSS animation when border's size change

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, border

I have a little probleme with my website: when I click on one of my boxes, the size of it changes, but without transition, even if I put transitions everywhere in my CSS. Here is my code and screens.
Thanks for your help.
Edit : I add my code in snippet, sry
Basically, my code works well, I juste want the transition when I close a box to be less brutal. If you don't want to check all the code, the variables starting by -tran are times (between 200 and 1000 ms).

[first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NWUW.png)
[second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgvzd.png)

```js
const   body = document.querySelector("body"),
        sidebar = body.querySelector(".sidebar"),
        toggle = body.querySelector(".toggle"),
        searchBtn = body.querySelector(".search-box"),
        modeSwitch = body.querySelector(".toggle-switch"),
        modeText = body.querySelector(".mode-text"),
        moi = body.querySelector(".article"),
        afficher_moi = body.querySelector(".afficher_moi");

        toggle.addEventListener("click", () =>{
            sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
        });

        searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>{
            sidebar.classList.remove("close");
        });

        modeSwitch.addEventListener("click", () =>{
            body.classList.toggle("dark");

            if(body.classList.contains("dark")){
                modeText.innerText = "Light Mode";
            }
            else{
                modeText.innerText = "Dark Mode";
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".article1").click(function () {
              $(".article1").toggleClass("close");
            });
          });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".article2").click(function () {
              $(".article2").toggleClass("close");
            });
          });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".article3").click(function () {
              $(".article3").toggleClass("close");
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".article4").click(function () {
              $(".article4").toggleClass("close");
            });
        });
```

```css
/* Importation des polices */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');


/* Tout */
*{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Initialisation des variables au lancement */
:root{
    --body-color: #e4e9f7;
    --sidebar-color: #fff;
    --primary-color: #695cfe;
    --primary-color-light: #f6f5ff;
    --toggle-color: #ddd;
    --text-color: #707070;


    --tran-02: all 0.2s ease;
    --tran-03: all 0.3s ease;
    --tran-04: all 0.4s ease;
    --tran-05: all 0.5s ease;
    --tran-10: all 1s ease;

}


/* Body */
body{
    height: 100vh;
    background: var(--body-color);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

body.dark{
    --body-color: #18191a;
    --sidebar-color: #242526;
    --primary-color: #3a3b3c;
    --primary-color-light: #3a3b3c;
    --toggle-color: #fff;
    --text-color: #ccc;
}

body.dark .sidebar header .toggle{
    color: var(--text-color);
}

body.dark .sidebar li a:hover .icon, body.dark .sidebar li a:hover .text{
    color: var(--text-color);
}

body.dark .menu-bar .mode i.sun{
    opacity: 1;
}

body.dark .menu-bar .mode i.moon{
    opacity: 0;
}

body.dark .switch::before{
    left: 1.25vw;
}

/* sidebar */
.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 13vw;
    padding: 0.925vh 0.73vw;
    background: var(--sidebar-color);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
    z-index: 100;
}

.sidebar header .toggle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -1.302vw;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
    height: 1.302vw;
    width: 1.302vw;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: var(--sidebar-color);
    font-size: 1.145vw;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.sidebar .text{
    font-size: 0.83vw;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--text-color);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar .image{
    min-width: 3.125vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.sidebar li{
    height: 4.63vh;
    margin-top: 0.93vh;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.sidebar li .icon{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 1.042vw;
    min-width: 3.125vw;
}

.sidebar li .icon, .sidebar li .text{
    color: var(--text-color);  
    transition: var(--tran-05);  
}

.sidebar .image-text img{
    width: 2.08vw;
    border-radius: 0.3125vw;
}

.sidebar .search-box{
    background: var(--primary-color-light);
    border-radius: 0.3125vw;
    transition: var(--tran-05)
}

.sidebar .menu{
    margin-top: 3.24vh;
}

.sidebar li a{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 0.3125vw;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.sidebar.close header .toggle{
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar .menu-bar{
    height: calc(100% - 4.63vh);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* sidebar header */
.sidebar header{
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar header .image-text{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/* sidebar close */
.sidebar.close{
    width: 4.58vw;
}

.sidebar.close .text{
    opacity: 0;
}

.sidebar.close ~ .home{
    left: 4.58vw;
    width: calc(100% - 4.58vw);
}

/* header */
header .image-text .header-text{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.header-text .name{
    font-weight: 600;
}

.header-text .profession{
    margin-top: -0.104vw;;
}

/* searchbox */
.search-box input{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.3125vw;
    font-size: 0.83vw;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: var(--primary-color-light);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

/* menu */

.menu-bar .mode{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.3125vw;
    background-color: var(--primary-color-light);
}

.menu-bar .mode .dark-light{
    height: 4.63vh;
    width: 3.125vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu-bar .mode i{
    position: absolute;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.menu-bar .mode i.sun{
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-bar .mode .toggle-switch{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 3.125vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.3125vw;
    background: var(--primary-color-light);
}

/* toggle-switch & switch */

.toggle-switch .switch{
    position: relative;
    height: 2.04vh;
    width: 2.29vw;
    border-radius: 1.3vw;
    background: var(--toggle-color);
}

.switch::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 1.39vh;
    width: 0.78vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0.26vw;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: var(--sidebar-color);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

/* Pages */

/* Accueil (home) */


.home{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 13.02vw;
    right: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 13.02vw);
    background: var(--body-color);
}

.home .text{
    font-size: 1.5625vw;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--text-color);
    padding: 0.74vh 2.08vw;
}

.home .text article{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 2%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid 1px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    opacity: 1;
    /* float: left; */
}

.home .text article.close{
    transition: var(--tran-05);
    height: 100%;
}

.home .text article .description .afficher_moi{
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(50%) rotate(180deg);
    height: 1.302vw;
    width: 1.302vw;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: var(--toggle-color);
    font-size: 1.145vw;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
    z-index: 100;
    top: 30%;
    right: 10%;
}

.home .text article.close .afficher_moi{
    transform: translateY(50%);
}

.home .text article.close p{
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

/* évenement */
.sidebar li a:hover{
    background: var(--primary-color);
}

.sidebar li a:hover .icon, .sidebar li a:hover .text{
    color: var(--sidebar-color);
}

.home .text article:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Slidebar + Dark  mode</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script async src="/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="sidebar close">
        <header>
            <div class="image-text">
                <span class="image">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
                </span>

                <div class="text header-text">
                    <span class="name">Lucas DUMONT</span>
                    <span class="profession">Etudiant</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <i class='bx bx-chevron-right toggle'></i>
        </header>

        <div class="menu-bar">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="search-box">
                        <i class='bx bx-search-alt icon' ></i>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Rechercher ...">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="menu-links">
                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class='bx bx-home icon'></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">Accueil</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class='bx bx-spreadsheet icon'></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">CV</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class='bx bxs-graduation icon'></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">Projets</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class='bx bx-happy-alt icon'></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">Loisirs</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class='bx bx-chat icon'></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">Contact</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="bottom-content">
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class='bx bx-home icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">Se connecter</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mode">
                        <div class="dark-light">
                            <i class='bx bx-moon icon moon' ></i>
                            <i class='bx bx-sun icon sun' ></i>
                        </div>
                        <span class="mode-text text">Dark Mode</span>

                        <div class="toggle-switch">
                            <span class="switch"></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <section class="home">
        <div class="text">
            <h2>Bienvenue sur mon site</h2>
            <article class="article1 close">
                <div class="description">
                    <h3>A propos de moi</h3>
                    <i class='bx bx-chevron-down afficher_moi'></i>
                </div>

                <p class="a_propos">
                    Insérer description de moi
                </p>
            </article>
            <article class="article2 close">
                <div class="description">
                    <h3>A propos de moi</h3>
                    <i class='bx bx-chevron-down afficher_moi'></i>
                </div>

                <p class="a_propos">
                    Insérer description de moi
                </p>
            </article>
            <article class="article3 close">
                <div class="description">
                    <h3>A propos de moi</h3>
                    <i class='bx bx-chevron-down afficher_moi'></i>
                </div>

                <p class="a_propos">
                    Insérer description de moi
                </p>
            </article>
            <article class="article4 close">
                <div class="description">
                    <h3>A propos de moi</h3>
                    <i class='bx bx-chevron-down afficher_moi'></i>
                </div>

                <p class="a_propos">
                    Insérer description de moi
                </p>
            </article>
        
        
        
        
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the value of `--tran-05`?

Comment: Please insert the CSS as a snippet, along with the HTML. That way everybody can run it and copy/modify as needed.

Comment: Sorry, I just did it !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS : box-sizing:border-box?

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Just tried it, it changed nothing :'(

Comment: try to post a working fiddle of the code, will help everyone debug is properly.
jsfiddle maybe

Comment: A snippet isn't enough ? I don't know how to give you a jsfiddle